# jquery each fadein input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to fade in an input box for the number given, If I had 5 as the number I would like to fade in 5 input boxes. can someone help?

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
     var num = $('#num').val();

$.each(function() {
         $('.box').fadeIn('fast').html('<input type="text">');//I need five input boxes
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) call is incorrect. Try simple `for` loop:

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
    var num = parseInt($('#num').val());
    var html = '';

    for (; num > 0; num--) {
        html += '<input type="text">';
    }

    $('.box').html(html).fadeIn('fast');
});
```